# Класс uses or overrides a deprecated API

Tags: java, cmd

Есть такой  класс:

```
public class CreatorInit extends Creator {
String direct;
public CreatorInit(String direct) {
    this.direct = direct;
}
@Override
public Command factoryMethod() {
    Object a = null;
    try {
        Class clazz = Class.forName(direct);
        a = clazz.newInstance();
        return (Command) a;
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {System.out.print("ClassNotFoundException");}
    catch (InstantiationException e) {System.out.print("InstantiationException");}
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {System.out.print("IllegalAccessException");}
    return (Command) a;
}
}
```

При создании объекта этого класса возникают следующие строки в консоли:

```
 C:\Users\ddyak\IdeaProjects\test_project>javac -sourcepath ./src -d bin 
src/ru/nsu/yakovlev/LogoWorld/Main.java
Note: .\src\ru\nsu\yakovlev\LogoWorld\factory\creators\CreatorInit.java uses 
or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

C:\Users\ddyak\IdeaProjects\test_project>javac -Xlint:deprecation -
sourcepath ./src -d bin src/ru/nsu/yakovlev/LogoWorld/Main.java
.\src\ru\nsu\yakovlev\LogoWorld\factory\creators\CreatorInit.java:14: 
warning: [deprecation] newInstance() in Class has been deprecated
        a = clazz.newInstance();
                 ^
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in class Class
1 warning
```

Как убрать предупреждение или его проигнорировать?

Comment: "clazz.newInstance()" can be replaced by  "clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()"

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--):

данный метод устарел, так как может кинуть любое исключение произошедшее в конструкторе без параметров, включая проверяемые. Использование данного метода фактически позволяет обойти проверку исключений во время компиляции. Метод [Constructor.newInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-) позволяет избежать этой проблемы оборачивая любое исключение внутри конструктора в (проверяемое) InvocationTargetException.

Вызов

```
clazz.newInstance()
```

может быть заменен на

```
clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()
```

---

Таким образом в коде вопроса необходимо заменить

```
 a = clazz.newInstance();
```

на

```
 a = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
```